# How can I use numpy to composite N layers of grayscale image data with each layer colorized in RGB space?

Tags: numpy, python-imaging-library

Consider this trivial example with three colors (red, blue, and green):

```
layers = {
  'red': np.random.rand(100, 100),
  'blu': np.random.rand(100, 100),
  'grn': np.random.rand(100, 100)
}

# Express composite as 3-channel RGB data
composite_arr = np.zeros(shape=(100, 100, 3))

# For each channel red, blue, and green, insert the data for the corresponding layer
composite_arr[:, :, 0] = layers['red']
composite_arr[:, :, 1] = layers['blu']
composite_arr[:, :, 2] = layers['grn']

# Finally, output the image expressed in RGB
composite_img = Image.fromarray(np.array(composite_arr * 255, dtype=np.uint8), mode="RGB")
composite_img.save('test.png')
```

---

Now, instead of the above example, let's try that with a list containing four layers:

```
layers = [
    np.random.rand(100, 100),
    np.random.rand(100, 100),
    np.random.rand(100, 100),
    np.random.rand(100, 100)
}
```

Let's say we choose four tetradic colors in the RGB space to apply one to each layer:

```
colors = {
    (1, 0, 0),
    (0, 1, 1),
    (0, 0, 1),
    (1, 1, 0)
}
```

How can I similarly build a composite for four layers in the above example?

Now, what about for any number of layers and colors?

I am looking for some generalized expression that I can apply sequentially to `composite_arr` that will update it for any number of layers and colors.

Alternatively, if this can be done efficiently using `PIL` or a similar library to colorize each layer and the apply some composite function, please suggest how that can be done.

Thanks!

---

Edit: To clarify, I would like the end result to be expressed in RGB space. So any number of layers should fit into this (following the above examples of 100x100 images):

```
composite_arr = np.zeros(shape=(100, 100, 3))
```

Comment: AFAIK, PIL doesn't support an arbitrary number of channels, just the specifically listed ones here... https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes

Comment: AFAIK, **Wand** supports up to 32 channels, and `libvips` supports an arbitrary number of channels. Both have Python interfaces.Try adding either or both the tags to get attention of appropriate folks.

Comment: @Mark Setchell - I understand that. I am trying to express the end result in 3-channel RGB space regardless of the number of layers.

I will check out Wand and vips to see if they can fit the needs that I am looking for, but ideally I would like to do this with an expression in numpy to update the array, similar to the trivial example.

Comment: Do you have a working solution for the list of 4 layers sample, to get an idea about the expected output?

Comment: @Divakar No, but my thinking is that if I can solve it for four layers, it should be solvable for N layers.

Comment: But we need to have an idea by possibly looking at a solution that solves it for those sample 4 layers and hopefully that could be extended/vectorized to N layers.

Comment: @Divakar That is what I am trying to solve.

Comment: Can you give some concrete example please? You want to put 4 or more layers in a 3-channel image? How? What do the 4 layers represent physically?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I suppose part of the problem is that I need to able to define that.